# How to configure a second IP address (to bind it to a VBoxHeadless virtual machine then)?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, routing, virtualbox, interface

I've requested my ISP to dedicate me a second Internet IP address and have got it. Now I need to configure it (I've never had any experience with using multiple IP addresses on one network interface) on my Ubuntu 10.04 server so that it will be a public address of a VirtualBox (VBoxHeadless) machine (running Ubuntu 10.04 Server as well). Would you be so kind to tell me how can I do so, or at least what docs to read and what specific subjects to google for?

Answer (score 1):

The simple manual way looks like this:

```
ip address add 192.168.0.200/24 broadcast + dev eth0
```

If you want to make this a permanent configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` you will have to use the older alias interface syntax (e.g., `eth0:1`), because that configuration file doesn't support multiple addresses per (primary) interface yet.  Add something like this:

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.200
    network 192.168.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```